# MS SQL unique key - bug or feature?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in MS SQL where I have a `TERMINAL varchar(50)` column and I have a unique key on it. 
I get a UK key violation exception when I try to insert record 'HOST1' and then 'HOST1 '.
Why MS sql handles these two strings as they would be the same?

Thanks
Z

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that MS SQL strips the white space at the end for VARCHAR.

Comment: 1) ANSI SQL feature. 2) [sqlservercentral.com](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1079506-338-1.aspx#bm1080070)

Comment: Per the standard, what it technically does is *add* spaces to the shorter string. I've never managed to construct a scenario where adding spaces will obtain a different result than stripping them, but that's what the standard says.